# useLazyQuery Typescript Type Error: cannot find name 'accountId'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apollo

Getting the following `Type Error: "cannot find name 'accountId'"` when using `useLazyQuery` with Typescript. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
const CustomerSearch: FC = (): ReactElement => {
  type customerData = {
    id: string;
    email: string;
    accountId: string;
  }

  type customerVars = {
    accountId: string;
  }

  const [getCustomer, {data, error}] = useLazyQuery<customerData, customerVars>(GET_CUSTOMER), {variables: {accountId: accountId}}})
}

return (
  <button onClick={() => getCustomer({variables: {accountId: "1234"}})}
)
```

Comment: Because you don't defined `accountId`

Comment: Why do you need to define it? Doesn't it get passed in as a param by getCustomer()?

Comment: Because you use it. `{variables: {accountId: accountId}}`

Comment: Looks like the solution here is to set it to empty and then overwrite it in the function call, correct? So it would be `{ variables: { accountId: ""} }`

Comment: It depends on your code and logic